# Pass string from php to js function

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Unable to pass a string from a php page to another page's js function.

It is to display message after checked the adding item is existing in an array or not. I've tried either adding quotes or not in the alert statement
    1. with quotes in alert statement, javascript didn't convert the statement but just display it directly.
    2. without quotes in alert statement, Chrome says it's an error if without quotes.

add_product.php (js function):

```
function add_to_cart(){
  jQuery('#modal_errors').html("");
  var error='';
  var available =$("#size option:selected").data("available");
  var quantity = jQuery('#quantityInput').val();
  {document.getElementById("available").value = available;
     var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();
     jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'cart.php',
        method : 'post',
        data : data,
        success: function(){
            alert("<?php echo $respMsg; ?>");
            location.reload();},
        error : function(){alert("something wrong");}
                });
        return;
}
```

cart.php:

```
if ($duplicate==false){
    $respMsg="The item is in cart now.";
} else {
    $respMsg="You have added the item twice.";
}
```

I expect a js msgbox popup to show either one of the php messages, but the actual output is either telling syntax error or displays the code string.

Comment: `echo $respMsg;`

Comment: Is the curly brace on the first character of this line a typo on your question? As it will cause a JS syntax error.

`{document.getElementById("available").value = available;`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use a function into `cart.php` returning the `$respMsg` result, then use `data` response from de jQuery.ajax function to alert the message:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url : 'cart.php',
   method : 'post',
   data : data,
   success: function(data){
              alert("Message: " + data);
              location.reload();
            },
   error : function(){
             alert("something wrong");
            }
});
```

More information about `data` response and `success` response, into [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**EDIT:**
Also you need to delete the curly brace here:

`{document.getElementById("available").value = available;`

It may cause JS syntax error.

Comment: In cart.php, I've added: echo $respMsg, tried to use data in success function as you suggest, but the output show the entire html code in msgbox. Also, the curly bracket is ok as it's just part of the js function.

Comment: Do you have any example to show me how the entire function at `cart.php` works? You need to `return $respMsg` into that function, and print it into JS function must be a` string` variable.

Comment: <p hidden><span id="cartMsg" class="text-alert"><?php if (isset($_SESSION["cartMsg"])) { echo "<script>alert('".$_SESSION["cartMsg"]."');</script>"           unset($_SESSION["cartMsg"]);}
else{echo "";} ?></span></p>

Comment: The cart.php file is working. At the moment, as above,  I'm using a SESSION to store the response from cart.php. And a hidden <p> has a js script to display the response in a msgbox. However, I've prefer to display the response via Ajax directly after it successfully post the add_to_cart product data the cart.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print your response, then you can't say `alert("<?php echo $respMsg; ?>");`

What you have to do is actually get the data in the callback and alert that data.

```
success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
},
```